# How do I set constraints to a rotated UISlider?

Tags: ios, rotation, autolayout, uislider

I can't seem to find a proper answer on SO. I'm trying to rotate a subclassed UISlider and apply constraints to position it properly, but can't seem to get it to work correctly. In the XIB it has constraints so that I don't have any issues with error showing. (Boss hates errors showing). So I remove the constraints first.

My code looks like this:

```
    removeConstraints([sliderHeight, sliderWidth, sliderLeading, sliderBottom])

    let rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    self.layer.transform = rotation

    let views = ["slider":slider, "deviceIcon":deviceIcon]
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[deviceIcon]-8-[slider]", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: deviceIcon, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: slider, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 115))

    addConstraints(constraints)
```

Once it runs, the frames look like this (white area between grey and orange vertical dashes is the thumb) :

[image: Vertical Slider with constraints]

It doesn't have the proper width/height and it isn't aligned to the bottom of the deviceIcon on its left. (I think it *might* be the proper distance from the deviceIcon, I can't tell.)

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is: Don't.  Simply adjust the existing leading and bottom constraints so that the rotated slider is in the proper position.